# Make an dynamically calculator

Tags: c#, calculator

i want to make an calculator.
my code till now is.

```
            string input;
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

            string curNumber = "";

            foreach (char c in input)
            {
               if (c =='+'|| c =='-'||c =='/'||c =='*')
               {
                   numbers.Add(curNumber);
                   curNumber = "";
               }
               else
               {
                   curNumber += c.ToString();
               }
            }
```

Now i dont know how i should work furhter with the numbers.
If the input is for example: 20+3+13-17.
How can i calculate the numbers?
How would u implement that logic in my code?

Comment: hack: use existing method `DataTable.Compute`: `string input = "100+20+3-17+2+7/3+3%2+100*10"; var dt = new System.Data.DataTable(); var result = dt.Compute(input, null);` // result = 1111.33333333333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var res = new DataTable().Compute("1-2/3*4", null);
```

---

**edit:** Also note you can use the fields in the data table to do functions like summing a column called "Total"

```
 var Total = DataTable().Compute("Sum(Total)", null);
```

Comment: Loool so easy?
I cant belive that it is so easy:D

Comment: Can u explain me what happen here or send me an link where it is explained?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you find any of the answers useful - please mark as 'answer' so other users will know there's a solution

Answer (score 2):

My preferred option will be using [NCalc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ncalc/)

Answer (score 1):

Another option will by using IronPython and IronRuby:

```
    var res = new IronPython.Hosting.PythonEngine().EvaluateAs<double>("1-2/3*4");
```

Comment: Can u explain me what happen here or send me an link where it is explained?